# elasticsearch update from 0.90 to 1.7 ruby on rails code does not work anymore

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, upgrade

Hello people I need help with Ruby on Rails.

Yesterday updated elasticsearch 0.90 to 1.7 and received this error

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [published-entities-production] No query registered for [text_phrase_prefix]
```

My autocomplete code which is not working anymore

```
 def self.autocomplete str
    Tire.search(Entity.index.name, :query => {:text_phrase_prefix => {:name => str}}).results.collect do |result|
      UnicodeUtils.downcase(result.name, :lt).gsub(/[^\p{word}]+/u, ' ').gsub(/  +/, '').strip
    end.uniq
  end
```

Please help me solve a problem. /usr/share/elasticsearch/data exists

Comment: I don't have much experience with ruby however this error seems to point that the query you construct is invalid, can you give us the query your application sends to your elasticsearch ?